# Can we say "get on the ground/ floor" instead of "get out of the pool"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

We often say to our children who is in a pool "**get out of the pool now**" or "**get out of the water now**".

[image]

Now, if you are forced to say "**get on**", then what is the area on the picture called?

or example, "**Please get on the ground now**" or "**Please get on the floor now**"?

Comment: Well, I'd say 'get onto the edge of the pool'.

Comment: "Get on the ground" sounds very odd.  Yes, technically someone who is in the pool is not "on the ground", but ordering someone to "get on the ground" makes it sound like they're flying in the air or something.

Comment: @stangdon - or ordering them to lie flat for some reason.

Comment: I agree with Michael Harvey, the area in the photo would be called the "edge of the pool" or "the pool side" or "the side of the pool". So "**Get onto the side of the pool**" might do. But I wonder why you are forced to say "get on"? Why try and use an awkward phrase when there are the perfectly good idiomatic ones you quote in your first sentence.

Comment: Maybe it's regional, but I wouldn't normally hear an indoor walking surface referred to as "the ground"; normally it's "the floor".  Ground is usually used for natural outdoor land surfaces.

Answer (score 7):

The flat area outside a pool is called the **(pool) deck**.

So if you are *forced* to use "get on", then, "*Get on the (pool) deck*" is the correct and clear.

Further, "Get on the ground" idiomatically means something like, "*Lie down on the ground*", as if there's danger of an explosion, or a police officer is giving orders to a suspect at gunpoint.

We never use "floor" to refer to the ground around a pool.

Comment: Maybe it's regional, but I would refer to the walking area around the pool as the floor. "Ground" is reserved for natural outdoor land surfaces

Comment: I'd still say "Get out onto the (pool) deck".

Comment: @M.Justin - I agree that a floor is inside a building, and the ground is outside (save for e.g. the forest floor), but many British speakers call both of these the 'floor', much to the annoyance of people like me.

Answer (score 0):

It is the "poolside".

> **OED** **poolside**: **A.** n. **The area beside a pool, now esp. a swimming pool.**
>
> 2000   A. L. Kennedy Everything you Need 163   *At poolsides, on patios, on boat decks: all the fashionable spots for lounging.*